# Coding a Connect four game. checkWin() not working properly. Skipping first and last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure you guys get a million posts like this, so I want to apologize right off the bat. I'm sure this is pretty simple.

The function in question, checkWin(), isn't complete yet, but it takes in a list of columns made up of jquery objects and iterates through them. The first two lines, which check for diagonal wins, are working as intended, though i'm sure they could be written more cleanly. For some reason the third if statement, which checks if a player has won by a vertical column works perfectly except it is completely skipping the first and last columns. It reports wins in all other columns correctly but completely ignores the first and last ones. I'm definitely a new to this so i'm sure it's some simple mistake i've made. I can attach the HTML code as well if that would help at all.

edit: Ive added the HTML and the CSS page as well. That way you can actually run the page.

```js
var col1 = [$("#a1"), $("#b1"), $("#c1"), $("#d1"), $("#e1"), $("#f1")]
var col2 = [$("#a2"), $("#b2"), $("#c2"), $("#d2"), $("#e2"), $("#f2")]
var col3 = [$("#a3"), $("#b3"), $("#c3"), $("#d3"), $("#e3"), $("#f3")]
var col4 = [$("#a4"), $("#b4"), $("#c4"), $("#d4"), $("#e4"), $("#f4")]
var col5 = [$("#a5"), $("#b5"), $("#c5"), $("#d5"), $("#e5"), $("#f5")]
var col6 = [$("#a6"), $("#b6"), $("#c6"), $("#d6"), $("#e6"), $("#f6")]
var col7 = [$("#a7"), $("#b7"), $("#c7"), $("#d7"), $("#e7"), $("#f7")]
var colList = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7]
var dotList = $("td")
var jumboText = $("#jumbotext")
var gameOver = false
var playerTurn = "blue"
var redName = ""
var blueName = ""


function redDrop (column){
  for (var i = column.length -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (column[i].attr("class") === "dot") {
      column[i].toggleClass("reddot")
      playerTurn = "blue"
      break
    }
  }
}

function blueDrop (column){
  for (var i = column.length -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (column[i].attr("class") === "dot") {
      column[i].toggleClass("bluedot")
      playerTurn = "red"
      break
    }
  }
}


function checkWin(){
  for (var i = 0; i < colList.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < colList[i].length; x++) {
      if (colList[i][x].attr("class") === "dot reddot" || colList[i][x].attr("class") === "dot bluedot") {
        try {
          if (colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i+1][x+1].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i+2][x+2].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i+3][x+3].attr("class")){
            alert(colList[i][x].attr("class")+"Winner!")
          }
          else if (colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i-1][x+1].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i-2][x+2].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i-3][x+3].attr("class")){
            alert(colList[i][x].attr("class")+"Winner!")
          }
////////
///////This next line seems to be the issue.
//////
          else if (colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i][x+1].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i][x+2].attr("class") && colList[i][x].attr("class") === colList[i][x+3].attr("class")){
            alert(colList[i][x].attr("class")+"Winner!")
          }

        } catch (e) {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function dropPeice(col){
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    col[i].click(function(){
        if (playerTurn === "blue") {
          blueDrop(col)
          playerTurn = "red"
          checkWin()
          jumboText.text(redName+": It's your turn. Place a red peice.")
        }else if (playerTurn === "red") {
          redDrop(col)
          playerTurn = "blue"
          checkWin()
          jumboText.text(blueName+": It's your turn. Place a blue peice.")
        }
    })
  }
}

function gamePlay(){
  blueName = prompt("Blue player, please input your name.")
  redName = prompt("Red player, please input your name.")
  jumboText.text(blueName+": You start. Place a blue piece.")
  for (var i = 0; i < colList.length; i++) {
    dropPeice(colList[i])
  }
}
gamePlay()
```

```css
.dot{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.reddot{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid maroon;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bluedot{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid navy;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connect 4</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FrontEndMaster.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron" align="center">
        <h1>Connect 4</h1>
        <p id= "jumbotext">This text will change to inform the player what's happening.</p>
      </div>
      <table align='center'>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "a1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "a7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "b1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "b7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "c1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "c7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "d1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "d7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "e1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "e7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="dot" id = "f1"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f2"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f3"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f4"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f5"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f6"></td>
          <td class="dot" id = "f7"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="FrontEndScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add the html and jquery so that the code snippet works. Alternatively if you've found the broken function then you can post a minimal example instead of the whole script

Comment: Small unrelated tip: you should use semi colons at the end of your JS lines :)

Comment: Good point sam! I'll definitelly do that as soon as ive figured this little issue out. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I have now added the HTML as well as the CSS so the code can be run in full!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are swallowing exceptions in your `try/catch` block. You are accessing indexes outside the array and not all if/else conditions are being tested.

This is a great example why you should avoid try catches (and use it in exceptional cases only); not because you don't want to write checks that you are actually accessing a valid index of the array.

The simplest solution I found was to create a `getClass` function that does the index checking and returns undefined for the cases where the index is out of bounds. By adding that check, there are no exceptions in your code and it works as expected

```js
var col1 = [$("#a1"), $("#b1"), $("#c1"), $("#d1"), $("#e1"), $("#f1")];
var col2 = [$("#a2"), $("#b2"), $("#c2"), $("#d2"), $("#e2"), $("#f2")];
var col3 = [$("#a3"), $("#b3"), $("#c3"), $("#d3"), $("#e3"), $("#f3")];
var col4 = [$("#a4"), $("#b4"), $("#c4"), $("#d4"), $("#e4"), $("#f4")];
var col5 = [$("#a5"), $("#b5"), $("#c5"), $("#d5"), $("#e5"), $("#f5")];
var col6 = [$("#a6"), $("#b6"), $("#c6"), $("#d6"), $("#e6"), $("#f6")];
var col7 = [$("#a7"), $("#b7"), $("#c7"), $("#d7"), $("#e7"), $("#f7")];
var colList = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7];
var dotList = $("td");
var jumboText = $("#jumbotext");
var gameOver = false;
var playerTurn = "blue";
var redName = "";
var blueName = "";


function redDrop(column) {
  for (var i = column.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (column[i].attr("class") === "dot") {
      column[i].toggleClass("reddot");
      playerTurn = "blue";
      break;
    }
  }
}

function blueDrop(column) {
  for (var i = column.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (column[i].attr("class") === "dot") {
      column[i].toggleClass("bluedot");
      playerTurn = "red";
      break;
    }
  }
}

function getClass(x, y) {
  const cell = colList[y] && colList[y][x];
  return cell && cell.attr("class");
}

function checkWin() {

  const boardSize = colList.length;
  for (var y = 0; y < boardSize; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++) {
      // Found a blue or red dot
      const className = getClass(x, y);
      if (className === "dot reddot" || className === "dot bluedot") {
        // Look diagonally down/right
        if (className === getClass(x + 1, y + 1) &&
          className === getClass(x + 2, y + 2) &&
          className === getClass(x + 3, y + 3)) {
          alert(className + "Winner!");
          return;
        }
        // Look diagonally up/right
        if (className === getClass(x + 1, y - 1) &&
          className === getClass(x + 2, y - 2) &&
          className === getClass(x + 3, y - 3)) {
          alert(className + "Winner!");
          return;
        }
        // Look down
        if (
          className === getClass(x + 1, y) &&
          className === getClass(x + 2, y) &&
          className === getClass(x + 3, y)) {
          alert(className + "Winner!");
          return;
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

function dropPeice(col) {
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    col[i].click(function() {
      if (playerTurn === "blue") {
        blueDrop(col);
        playerTurn = "red";
        checkWin();
        jumboText.text(redName + ": It's your turn. Place a red peice.");
      } else if (playerTurn === "red") {
        redDrop(col);
        playerTurn = "blue";
        checkWin();
        jumboText.text(blueName + ": It's your turn. Place a blue peice.");
      }
    });
  }
}

function gamePlay() {
  blueName = prompt("Blue player, please input your name.");
  redName = prompt("Red player, please input your name.");
  jumboText.text(blueName + ": You start. Place a blue piece.");
  for (var i = 0; i < colList.length; i++) {
    dropPeice(colList[i]);
  }
}

gamePlay();
```

```css
.dot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reddot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid maroon;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bluedot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid navy;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Connect 4</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="FrontEndMaster.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" align="center">
      <h1>Connect 4</h1>
      <p id="jumbotext">This text will change to inform the player what's happening.</p>
    </div>
    <table align='center'>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="a1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="a7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="b1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="b7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="c1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="c7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="d1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="d7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="e1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="e7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dot" id="f1"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f2"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f3"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f4"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f5"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f6"></td>
        <td class="dot" id="f7"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="FrontEndScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And an extra thanks for the education about try catches! I'll definitely keep that in mind going forward.